# message_handler(content_types = ["text"]) не работает, но и ошибок не выдает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

python код с библиотекой telebot
В коде 2 ивента, 1 после **/start**, второй после ввода любого текстового сообщения, после запуска кода, если написать боту **/старт**, бот отпишет: `"добро пожаловать"`, но после ввода любого текстового сообщения, бот ничего не делает(а должен отправить само сообщение, и потом отправить `"Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?"`), но в консоль `print('update')` записывает.
в консоль никаких ошибок не возвращает, в чём проблема?

```
import telebot
import time
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать')

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    print('echo')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")

while True:
    try:
        print('update')
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error')
        time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

В третий раз переустановил библиотеку, и она чудом заработала.

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip install -U pytelegrambotapi
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Кст, а зачем было ставить `telebot`? Он ведь не с `pytelegrambotapi` поставился?

Comment: удалили 1 библиотеку, установили другую. И вправду чудо

Comment: @gil9red ну да я её поставил вместе с `pytelegrambotapi `, но саама проблема била в отдельной библиотеке `telebot`