# не получается запустить телеграмм бота, выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telebot

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config ()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
import telebot
#import pyowm

owm = OWM('токен', config_dict) 
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    answer = "В жопе " + message.text + "сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n\n"
    answer += "Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "\n\n"
    if temp < 10:
        answer += "сейчас жопа как холодно, одевайся как якут! "
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += "Сейчас холодно, оденься потеплее. "
    else:
        answer += "Температура норм, одевай шорты и тапки. "
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.infinity_polling( none_stop = True )
```

Comment: а какая у вас ошибка мы догадаться должны?

Comment: Убедитесь, что сказали pytelegrambotapi, pyowm и telebot, все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможно неправильно установленна библиотека `telebot`, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350165/message-handlercontent-types-text-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82) есть решение.
Более точнее можно сказать, зная ошибку.